# Searching verb + noun in a table

Tags: php, sql

**Information**

I have a table which lists verbs & adjectives. I also have a table which lists nouns. And my third table is our search field.

**What do I want to do?**

I want to search that verbs + adjectives in our search field table. So I want to find *verb + noun* or *adjective + noun*

**Examples**

We have records on our search field table:

1. buildawall
2. redtree
3. countonyou
4. purchaseanapple

**Conclusion**

So I have that words in my verbs + adjectives table and nouns table (build,wall,red,tree,purchase,apple,count,you) How can I find them in correct order by my nouns and adjective + verbs tables? What I mean by correct order is it should be *verb + noun* or *adjective + noun*

Ps: You know sometimes we need prepositions in english. But I don't mind them in that search. To don't mind the prepositions these types of results are correct for me:

verb + (any character(s)) + noun

adjective + (any character(s)) + noun

**What I've tried?**

Well, I've tried a sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM adjectiveVerbList INNER JOIN searchField ON searchField.text LIKE CONCAT('%',adjectiveVerbList.word, '%')
```

But as you can see this query is just a simple like query. It does not work. **By the way I can do it with php or just a sql query it doesn't matter.**

Edit: My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `adjectiveVerbList` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `word` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('adjective','verb') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `adjectiveVerbList` (`id`, `word`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'abandoned', 'adjective'),
(2, 'able', 'adjective'),
(3, 'absolute', 'adjective'),
(4, 'adorable', 'adjective'),
(5, 'adventurous', 'adjective'),
(6, 'academic', 'adjective'),
(7, 'acceptable', 'adjective'),
(8, 'acclaimed', 'adjective'),
(9, 'accomplished', 'adjective'),
(10, 'accurate', 'adjective'),
(11, 'aching', 'adjective'),
(12, 'acidic', 'adjective'),
(13, 'acrobatic', 'adjective'),
(14, 'active', 'adjective'),
(2363, 'whip', 'verb')



CREATE TABLE `nounList` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `word` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Tablo döküm verisi `nounList`
--

INSERT INTO `nounList` (`id`, `word`) VALUES
(1, 'ATM'),
(2, 'CD'),
(3, 'SUV'),
(4, 'TV'),
(5, 'aardvark'),
(6, 'abacus'),
(7, 'abbey'),
(8, 'abbreviation'),
(9, 'abdomen'),
(10, 'ability')


CREATE TABLE `searchField` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `word` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `searchField` (`id`, `word`) VALUES
(1, 'buildawall')
(2, 'redtree')
(3, 'greenmybuild')
...
```

**Input**

buildawall (that comes from searchField table)

**Output**

It is correct because we have 'build' word from *adjectiveVerbList* and 'wall' from *nounList* table. And build comes before the wall so it is readable.

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] to include some sample data, and the result you would want from that input? It would be much easier to follow with a specific example.

Comment: A DB Fiddle of some sort would also help.  And how do you handle cases like "count" which is a verb and "counter" which is a noun -- and there are zillions of cases like this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd even go as far as point out that count's a noun too and, worse, some are all 3; express your express wish to read the Express/back the jockey on the back horse's back!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I downloaded a txt for nouns,verbs and adjectives. And added all of them to the database. So I am comparing with them

Comment: @TolgayToklar OK, that's the first half of what we asked for; now please show us the expected output for that input.

Comment: @IMSoP I added example input / output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to your object names.
I put the data into a preceding WITH clause, I'll mark where the "real" query starts. You did not specify what output you wanted, though, so I just assumed something. And I used data that matches your first search phrases.

```
WITH
-- input ....
phrases(id,phrase) AS (
          SELECT 1,'buildawall'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'redtree'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'countonyou'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'purchaseanapple'
)
,
adjectiveverblist (id,word,type) AS (
          SELECT 1,'build'    ,'verb'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'red'      ,'adjective'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'count'    ,'verb'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'purchase' ,'verb'
)
,
nounlist(id,word) AS (
          SELECT 1,'wall'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'tree'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'you'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'apple'
)
-- end of input - real query starts here ...
SELECT
  phrase
, av.word AS adjective_verb
, av.type AS av_type
, n.word  AS noun
FROM phrases
JOIN adjectiveverblist av ON phrase LIKE '%' + av.word + '%'
JOIN nounlist n ON phrase LIKE '%' + n.word + '%'
;
-- out      phrase      | adjective_verb |  av_type  | noun  
-- out -----------------+----------------+-----------+-------
-- out  redtree         | red            | adjective | tree
-- out  buildawall      | build          | verb      | wall
-- out  countonyou      | count          | verb      | you
-- out  purchaseanapple | purchase       | verb      | apple
```

Comment: I added my tables to my question. Could you check it?

Comment: Is this for mssql? Because I am getting FUNCTION REGEXP_LIKE does not exist error on mysql

Comment: MS Sql is one of the DBMS-s that does not support regular expressions. So, use LIKE, and concat the noun/adjective/verb with the percent sign before and after. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I want. But it is running very slow. Because I have 7K nouns and 2k verbs. Also I have 44K rows in the pharases table

Comment: A `LIKE` predicate in a join is bound to be slow. The DBMS has physically no means to optimise the access plan if it has to parse a string to satisfy a join condition. With that design, I'm afraid it is as good as it gets ...

Comment: How can I prevent these type of results? https://imgur.com/a/XovILBb

Comment: You can only prevent that if you go through a very extensive exercise of stemming and precedence. And even that is not absolutely watertight. I't s impossible to distinguish `thing` in `nicething` from `thin` in `thinguy` ....